# Why cant a View have a backgroundcolor when used in a TouchableHighlight?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a custom component and want to use a TouchableHighlight with a nested view in it. The TouchableHighlight has an underlaycolor, but when I assign a backgroundcolor to the view, the underlaycolor from the TouchableHighlight don't work anymore.

If I set the backgroundcolor in the view to white, it will not work:

```
<TouchableHighlight 
    style={{flex:1}} 
    underlayColor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
    onPress={this._changeHeight}>
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
          <Text>Thats a test</Text>
      </View>      
</TouchableHighlight>
```

But if i do it like this, withought a backgroundcolor in the view, it will work:

```
<TouchableHighlight 
    style={{flex:1}} 
    underlayColor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
    onPress={this._changeHeight}>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <Text>Thats a test</Text>
      </View>      
</TouchableHighlight>
```

I expected that the underlaycolor still works, even if a view has a backgroundcolor. The View is a child and I thought the touchable is the parent. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

Add background color also in rgba format

```
backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
```

Comment: You mean i should add this to the style of the touchable? I tried it now for more then 2 hours but it dont work.

Comment: I was talking about adding it to view